# Machine values for arithmetic operations and castings in C++

Tags: c++, floating-point, precision

I am new in C++ programming. I'm wondering what possible machine values are obtained as the results of the following simple operations in C++:

```
int a = 3;
double inv_a;

inv_a =  (double) 1 / (double) a;
std::cout << "a*(1/a) = " << std::setprecision(30) << (double) a * inv_a << std::endl;
```

For example, I'd like to know if the output of

```
(double) a * inv_a
```

is always greater than or equal to 1.000...0 as a double or not for any possible int values of a. Is it possible to obtain values strictly less than 1 but very close to it like 0.999...? I'm concerning this for the case when I cast the result into int. Thank you in advance.

My experiments always gave me exact 1.

Comment: Yes it's possible. See the duplicate question.

Comment: *I am new in C/C++ programming* -- There is no such language as `C/C++`.  It's either `C` or it's `C++`.  Having said this, floating point issues occur in almost every single high-level language out there.  That's what the duplicate link is all about.

Comment: Don't tag C++ `std::cout` with the tag C. There is no such programming language C/C++. Almost any language is able to call CRT bindings, but you don't call it Python/C or C#/C for example.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: This is not a duplicate of that question. That question is a general address of the fact that floating-point arithmetic approximates real arithmetic. This post asks a specific question that is not addressed in the other question, unless it some answer incidentally mentions it (which still would not qualify this as a duplicate, as some buried incidental mention is not a useful duplicate).

Comment: Read more about [IEEE754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) the defacto standard for floating point representation in 2023.

Comment: You should read these: [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) , [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> For example, I'd like to know if the output of `(double) a * inv_a` is always greater than or equal to 1.000...0 as a double

The relationship does not hold since, using IEEE-754 binary64 (“double precision”) arithmetic, `1./49*49` yields 0.99999999999999988897769753748434595763683319091796875.

When the reciprocal gets into the subnormal range, results greater than 1 are possible. For example, with `a` = 2<sup>1023</sup>+2<sup>971</sup>, `1/a*a` is 1+2<sup>−52</sup>. This is because subnormal results have reduced precision that allows greater errors. In the normal range, this does not occur.

With all values involved (including the reciprocal) in the normal range, it is the inverse relationship that holds; `a * inv_a` is always less than or equal to 1 and is sometimes less.

In this answer, expressions in code font represents computations with floating-point. Expressions not in code font represent ordinary real-number arithmetic.

Here is a proof that as long as we stay in the normal range and use a base-two<sup>1</sup> floating-point format with round-to-nearest, no result greater than 1 is possible. Consider some *x*. Let *p* be a power of two such that *xp* is in [1, 2). As long as we are in the normal range, `1/x*x` = `1/(xp)*xp`, where `xp` = `x*p`, due to the nature of the floating-point representation. So there is an *x* such that 1< `1/x*x` only if there is such an *x* in [1, 2).

Since round-to-nearest is used and ½ < 1/*x* ≤ 1, `1/x` = 1/*x* +  for some  satisfying −½*u* ≤  ≤ +½*u*, where *u* is the unit of least precision for floating-point numbers in [½, 1). Then `1/x`•*x* = (1/*x* + )*x* = 1 + *x*. Since *x* < 2,  −½*u* ≤  ≤ +½*u* implies  −*u* < *x* < +*u*. Therefore `1/x`•*x* is within *u* of 1. Observe that *u*, the ULP for numbers in [½, 1), is half of the ULP for numbers in [1, 2). Therefore `1/x`•*x* is closer to 1 than it is to the next greater number in [1, 2). So, when computing `1/x*x`, rounding to nearest will not produce a result greater than 1.

For completeness, note that if `a` is zero, a NaN, or an infinity, a NaN will be produced by `1/a*a`, so that result will not be less than, equal to, or greater than 1. And, if `a` is subnormal, `1/a` can produce infinity, so `1/a*a` will be an infinity and will compare as greater than 1.

### Note

<sup>1</sup> I expect this holds for other bases but do not have a proof at hand.

Comment: Please, truncate (or round) that number to 15 digits. It's the amount of trusted digits for a 64 bits precision (the 16th is not always true). Rest of digits is just garbage.

Comment: @Ripi2: No, they are not garbage. They are mathematically determined. The IEEE-754 standard precisely defines the value of floating-point numbers, and the double-precision number just below 1 is exactly 0.99999999999999988897769753748434595763683319091796875. Further, rounding that to 15 digits would produce exactly 1, which would conceal the fact this question asks about.

Comment: Regarding `x * (1/x)` never exceeding 1: How about `x = 1.124225499393696e308`? This number is normal and `x * (1/x)` evaluates to `1.0000000000000002` in my Python shell.

Comment: @alias: As the answer says, “When the reciprocal gets into the subnormal range, results greater than 1 are possible.” The reciprocal of your `x` is about 8.895•10^−309 (in hexadecimal format, exactly 0x1.995b5c7804bbcp-1024), which is in the subnormal range. When the text following that says “With all values involved in the normal range,” the reciprocal is one of the values involved.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thank you! With your comment in mind, 'inv_a' has a mathematical value 1/a + &epsilon where |&epsilon| is less than some negative power of 2 and a*&epsilon may yield a discrepancy between the mathematical and machine values of a * inv_a? Whenever we multiply two floating numbers, a roundup operation is always performed besides 'cout'?

Comment: @pd: The general rule for floating-point operations is that, unless specified otherwise, the computed result is determined as if the mathematical result were fully determined and then rounded to the nearest value representable in the format (with some selection about rules for rounding direction, most often toward the nearest representable value with ties broken by favoring the number with even low digit in its floating-point representation). So, when analyzing floating-point operations or writing proofs, we can say the result is y+, where  is the amount of change produced by rounding…

Comment: … This includes multiplication as you ask about and it includes operations such as converting numbers in source code, like `3.14`, to the floating-point format.